# LINQ: Use an Array for the where filter

Tags: linq

I have a LINQ query where I'm filtering a list using where *multiple* WHERE statements.

```
string[] filters = new string[]{"a","b","c","d"};
var filtered = from n in bigList where n != "a" where n != "b" where n != "c" where n != "c" select n;
```

How do I use the *filters* array instead of having to write multiple where clauses?

Comment: Is this Linq-to-Objects or Linq-to-Entities?

Comment: …assuming it’s Linq-to-Objects I’m going to chastise you for wanting to use a `O(n*m)` time solution when instead if you used a HashSet it will do it in `O(n+m)` time.

Comment: Linq to objects, bigList is just a List<string>

Comment: Can you post an example of filter list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that `HashSet.Contains` is an `O(1)` operation, whereas `Array.Contains` is an `O(n)` operation.

<sub>Granted, if you only have 1-2 (maybe 3) values in the array and if the hashing algo or string data is particularly slow then Array.Contains might be faster, but consider that if you only have 1-3 elements then just use individual locals instead of an array because that will be even faster (as it will effectively be an unrolled-loop)</sub>

```cs
HashSet<String> filterValueSet;
{
    String[] filterValues = new String[]
    {
        "a", "b", "c", "d"
    };

    filterValueSet = new HashSet<String>( filterValues ); // Pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as the second argument for case-insensitive matching.
}

IReadOnlyList<String> filtered = bigList
    .Where( v => !filterValueSet.Contains( v ) )
    .ToList();
```

Using a `HashSet<String>` like this is the fastest way to filter a set of values.

---

If the above code looks intimidating, it can be reduced down to just this, though:

```cs
HashSet<String> filterValueSet = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }.ToHashSet();

IReadOnlyList<String> filtered = bigList
    .Where( v => !filterValueSet.Contains( v ) )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Can I suggest that you explain why `HashSet<string>` might be faster? And can you say what circumstances that it might actually be slower?

Comment: @Enigmativity `HashSet.Contains` is an `O(1)` operation, whereas `Array.Contains` is an `O(n)` operation. Granted, if you only have 1-2 (maybe 3) values in the array _and_ if the hashing algo or string data is particularly slow then `Array.Contains` _might_ be faster, but consider that if you only have 1-3 elements then just use individual locals instead of an array because that will be even faster (as it will effectively be an unrolled-loop).

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping you'd add that to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the Hashset performance. Noted....

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer, An array filtered by another array.

```
var filtered = bigList.Where(d => !filters.Contains(d));
```

Comment: This will run in `O(n*m)` time - try it when `filters` has 1024 items and `bigList` has 1024 items - it will take _ages_ to complete.